# ngClick doesn't work in my angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handlebars.js

I would like to assign a value to a variable through ng-click as shown in the tutorial page, but it doesn't work out jet. What am I doing wrong?

```
  <div ng-controller="PropertyCtrl" ng-init="active='Please select an option'">
    <div class="left-third" >
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="property in properties">
          <a href="" ng-click="active='{{property}}'">{{property}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right-rest">
      <h4>{{active}}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
function PropertyCtrl($scope){
    $scope.active;
    $scope.activate = function(property){
        $scope.active = property;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="" ng-click="activate(property);">{{property}}</a>
```